# Passing variables from for loop into another function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still very new to python. Please excuse any basic mistakes. I've been reading around and experimenting, but I haven't been able to get this to work.
The main function in my script prints out all the dates in one year. I want to pass each date value into the next function (fun_Phase1) until all dates in the year have been processed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
import json 
import calendar

def fun_Phase1(_DATE):
    # Run additional code here
    print "You are in function Phase1 and the date is " + _DATE

def fun_Main():
    cal = calendar.Calendar()
    for year in range(2015,2016):
        for month in range(1,13):
            monthdays = [d for d in cal.itermonthdays(year,month) if d != 0]
            for day in monthdays:
                str_year = str(year)
                if month < 10:
                    str_month = "0" + str(month)
                    # print(str_month)
                else:
                    str_month = str(month)
                    # print(str_month)
                if day < 10:
                    str_day = "0" + str(day)
                    # print(str_day)
                else:
                    str_day = str(day)
                    # print(str_day)
                _DATE = str_year + str_month  + str_day
                # print(_DATE)
                fun_Phase1(_DATE)

# Execute the code
fun_Main()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what isn't working about your code?

Comment: if you are running this with python3, you just need to change `print("You are in function Phase1 and the date is " + _DATE)`

Answer (score 1):

> I tried running your code but as @PRMoureu Said, You just need to change this

```
def fun_Phase1(_DATE):
    # Run additional code here
    print "You are in function Phase1 and the date is " + _DATE
```

to this

```
def fun_Phase1(_DATE):
    # Run additional code here
    print ("You are in function Phase1 and the date is " + _DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @PRMoureu and Tabaene Haque. After you confirmed that the logic was correct, I dug back into the errors that I was receiving and it turned out to be an indentation error. As mentioned before, I am still getting used to all the nuances of this language. After I fixed that up, as well as the print statement. It started working. Thanks again.